# Error in building kernel module sched_tp.ko

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, pahole

I have built Linux kernel with support FTrace and debug info following below instructions:

```
$ cd /path/to/linux-debug-workshop
$ source /path/to/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux
$ make training_defconfig
$ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_FTRACE
$ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO
$ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5
$ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
$ ./scripts/config -d CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
$ make -j$(nproc) Image dtbs modules
```

Above steps generate "vmlinux" under /path/to/linux-debug-workshop. I need to build kernel module sched_tp.ko following below instructions:

```
$ cd /path/to/lisa
$ source /path/to/poky/poky/3.1.9/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux
$ source init_env
$ ./tools/kmodules/build_module \
/path/to/linux-debug-workshop ./tools/kmodules/sched_tp/
```

I am getting the below error in the last step while trying to build:

```
Building module for ARCH=arm64
make: Entering directory 'linux-debug-workshop/lisa/tools/kmodules/sched_tp'
make -C /linux-debug-workshop M=/linux-debug-workshop/lisa/tools/kmodules/sched_tp modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/linux-debug-workshop'

pahole -F btf,dwarf -E --suppress_force_paddings --show_only_data_members --skip_missing --expand_types_once --expanded_prefix "KERNEL_PRIVATE_" -C file:///linux-debug-workshop/lisa/tools/kmodules/sched_tp/private_types.txt /linux-debug-workshop/vmlinux > _header

**pahole: /linux-debug-workshop/vmlinux: Invalid argument**
```

I have checked pahole version:v1.23

Comment: DWARF v5 is farly new. Does your pahole support it?

Comment: @stark seems like pahole started supporting DWARF5 back in 1.13 with additional support added along the way (1.20, 1.21, 1.23). Not sure if it supports everything that's needed though.